# How to "Grab" in "Edit" mode?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, edit-mode, transforms

[image]Just began learning.
Saw in the tutorial video how, the "grab circle" was used in "edit" mode while the "move" was selected.
Can't find any info how to do that ?
Can only select vertices, edges or faces.

Comment: You must select all vertices/edges of circle.

Comment: Sorry for misleading and not a proper explanation.
In the video there was a "grab circle" that has been used like a grab tool in "sculpting" mode, but the thing is that the grab has been used in "edit" mode without standart polygon selection.

Comment: Please add an image of your whole Blender window (via Window > Save Screenshot in Blender) so that we can see all the settings. At the moment I can just see that you have Proportional Editing enabled (use the 'O' key to disable it), but not whether viewport overlays are turned on. It would help to share you Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ too. Follow the instructions on that page.

Comment: Incidentally you'r not pointing to the 'grab circle' on your image. That's the circle of influence which you see when Proportional editing is turned on and you're actually moving the vertex. I suspect the 'grab circle' you actually mean is the smaller white one round the gizmo which you can grab to move the vertex around which is why I wanted to see if the viewport overlays were turned on.

Comment: Thank you so much, just need to know the name of that circle, its "Proportional Editing"